# Why is the __get() magic method called when trying to assign a reference to a property object?

Tags: php, reference, getter-setter

```
class Test
{
    public $prop1;
    public function __get(string $n)
    {
        echo '__GET: '.$n.' - but why?<br>';
        die;
    }
}

$t = new Test();
$x1 = new \stdClass();
$t->prop2 = &$x1;
echo '.';
die;
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/f7f16

here you can see, I create an `stdClass` object, try to pass it to a non-exists variable, and `__get()` gets executed - even though I was just tryting to write it, instead of reading. And if I didn't `die()` it, I get `Indirect modification of overloaded property has no effect` exception.

If I have this (no reference)

```
class Test
{
    public $prop1;
    public function __get(string $n)
    {
        echo '__GET: '.$n.' - but why?<br>';
        die;
    }
}

$t = new Test();
$x1 = new \stdClass();
$t->prop2 = $x1;
echo '.';
die;
```

https://onlinephp.io/c/3afef

everything works fine, but why?

Comment: My assumption would be that it needs to replace what the existing property references. There's no real point to assign a non-existing variable by reference because `__set` doesn't accept arguments by reference anyway

Comment: + i find it if alone __get() method is removed, no error occurs and all works well!

Comment: Yes you can always add non-existing properties to a class. `__get` and `__set` are typically so you can run more custom code

Comment: @JohnSmith: the `__get()` example fails due to **assigning by reference** (the property is not defined and PHP won't create it, no aliasing can be done, it is overloaded). And the `__set()` example works due to **assigning by value** (the property is not defined and PHP won't create it, aliasing is not required to do, it does not exists but that's not problem as it has been overloaded and does not trigger an undefined property warning).

Comment: ‘Indirect modification of overloaded property has no effect’ is not an exception, but a ‘notice’. The actual thrown error is ‘Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object’.

Comment: There’s a discussion [a while back](https://externals.io/message/47355) as it relates to arrays which behave in a similar way: https://3v4l.org/3sAtA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, PHP has a concept of ‘reading’ a property in order to perform a write/modify operation.  Though it may seem incoherent at first glance, this allows PHP to perform certain in-place modification operations with less overhead, that would otherwise have to rely on read-modify-write round-trips.  Situations where it is used include appending to an array and creating a new reference to the property.  For this to work with dynamically-resolved properties, the `__get` magic method must return a reference, which is to say, a place which can have its value modified; otherwise a notice will be triggered with the message ‘Indirect modification of overloaded property has no effect’.

```php
class Globalses {
    public function& __get(string $name) {
        echo "{$name} GET!\n";
        return $GLOBALS[$name];
    }
}

$obj = new Globalses;

$foo = [0, 1, 2, 3];
$obj->foo[] = 4;     // foo GET!
echo 'foo='; debug_zval_dump($foo);

$bar = 42;
$var =& $obj->bar;   // bar GET!
$var = 69;
echo 'bar='; debug_zval_dump($bar);
```

You will get this message in the above example if you remove the `&` from the declaration of `function& __get`, which will make the method return a value, and not a reference.

The same code path of ‘reading-in-order-to-modify’ is triggered when an object property is on the *left-hand* side of reference-assignment (`=&`).  But of course, if property lookup is performed dynamically by user code (what PHP misnames ‘overloading’), there is no way PHP can promise that ‘after `$obj->prop =& (expr)` is executed, accessing `$obj->prop` will resolve to the same thing `(expr)` did at that time’, so PHP throws an exception.  However, the interpreter realises this only after the `__get` magic method has already been invoked.

This can be seen by inspecting the source code of the Zend engine.  To evaluate an expression like `$obj->prop =& expr`, the Zend engine calls the function [`zend_assign_to_property_reference`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ff856494310e64387ac37c95fa35c93868952a4c/Zend/zend_execute.c#L3203-L3236).  This function invokes `zend_fetch_property_address` in order to determine which zval (an internal representation of a PHP value) to modify so that it becomes an alias for the same zval as the right-hand side expression.  It [does so](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ff856494310e64387ac37c95fa35c93868952a4c/Zend/zend_execute.c#L3152-L3160) by invoking the `get_property_ptr_ptr` internal method slot of the object; if that returns nothing, there is a fallback to the `read_property` slot.  For user-code objects, this means invoking the `zend_std_read_property` function, which is [where the call to the `__get` magic method is actually made](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/ff856494310e64387ac37c95fa35c93868952a4c/Zend/zend_object_handlers.c#L716-L723).

Again, because `zend_std_read_property` is called with flags that signify it is being ‘read-in-order-to-modify’, if `__get` happens not to return a reference (because it is not declared `function& __get`), an `E_NOTICE` error is raised.  But either way, `zend_std_read_property` will return its result in the zval prepared for it by `zend_fetch_property_address` instead of a pre-existing one, which causes the latter *not* to wrap it in a so-called [indirect zval](https://www.phpinternalsbook.com/php7/zvals/references.html#indirect-zvals) as `zend_assign_to_property_reference` expects, which causes that function in turn to throw an exception.

This is a pretty baroque implementation, if you ask me.  I even agree that the Zend engine could have been implemented so that by the point `__get` is about to be called, the interpreter realises it’s actually pointless to invoke and throws an exception immediately.  But given that this code path is hit only in user code that is incorrect and should be rewritten, perhaps it makes little sense to optimise.

If you compiled the list of things in PHP that make no sense, I’m not sure this would even make the top ten; the language is just that bizarre.  Get used to it.  Or don’t: changing the language is also an option.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign by reference<sup>1</sup>, the left hand variable needs to be defined (it exists) and if it doesn't (it is undefined), PHP will define it.

However not in the `$t->prop2` case:

The variable's member name (`$t->prop2`) is undefined but the `__get()`<sup>2</sup> magic method of `$t` dictates PHP to not define it as it would normally do, but instead pass on to `__get()` as first parameter the members' name, to obtain its overloaded value.

This is flawed, as to assign by reference *requires* the variable (or property) to be defined for a successful operation.  But undefined (overloaded) can not fulfill this.

Therefore the warning:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property stdClass@anonymous::$prop2 has no effect

and finally the fatal error:

> Cannot assign by reference to overloaded object

**Example Code**<sup>3,4</sup>

```php
$t = new class() extends stdClass
{
    public function __get(string $name) {
        $x = null;
        return $x;
    }
};

$t->prop2 = &$x1;
```

---

1. [Assignment by Reference - PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference)
2. [Property overloading - PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get)
3. [Example code on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OMo1A)
4. [Backwards compatible example code on 3v4l.org for historic view](https://3v4l.org/5bcXf)

Comment: "When you assign by reference1, the left hand variable needs to be defined" this alone explains it. But strange behaviour of php to be honest

Comment: @JohnSmith: Yes and thinking this boils down to: How to alias a property that does not exist as a property but only virtually (is overloaded)? To "un-strange", make it non-overloaded first, e.g. `$t->prop2 = null;`, then alias it: `$t->prop2 = &$x1;`. And thinking "variable aliasing" not "pointers", just names. In PHP we can't obtain the address of a variable by some function, only the reference (`&`) is available, but only in some limited places (assign by reference, return by reference etc.), and often not necessary to deal with. But then when we encounter it, tends to be strange ;).

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of complex explanations here is a simple answer as to why it's calling `__get()`,

```php
$obj = new \stdClass();
$test = "hello";
$obj->var = &%test;
```

Take the simple example above, to be able to set `$obj->var` to the memory address that `$test` points to, $obj->var needs a memory address inside $obj, without `__get` PHP will just create one on its own per the code above if your using `__get` PHP won't and needs you to define it. the only place you could do that definition is inside that `__get`

Answer (score -2):

[Per documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members):

> `__get()` is utilized for reading data from inaccessible (protected or private) or non-existing properties.

if you want to use `__get` by reference, here what you should write:

```
public function &__get ( $index )
```

Comment: Yes, you may be able to prepend & in front of the `__get` magic method which is indeed available for property overloading, but it can't prevent the overloading itself and therefore is not adequate for the assign by reference as in context of the question: the `&__get()` errors fatally the same as `__get()` does, it makes no difference. You should perhaps make this more visible that the use-case is certainly different from what has been asked about.

Comment: Although nothing is incorrect, I think the OP is more curious _why_ `__get` is invoked when setting a variable, but only by reference.